# Can't use float values in Vector3

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm currently working on a Unity project where I want to instantiate a roadSection GameObject when my player object enters a trigger collider (tagged as "Trigger"). The instantiation requires setting the position using Vector3, and I need to use float values for accuracy.

However, when I try to use float values in new Vector3(9.5, 0, 10.5), I encounter an issue. Unity seems to reject the float values in this context.

How can I correctly instantiate the roadSection GameObject with precise float values for the position in Unity? Is there a different approach or method I should be using?

Here's the relevant code snippet for reference:

```
public class SectionTrigger : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject roadSection;

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Trigger"))
        {   
            Instantiate(roadSection, new Vector3(9.5, 0, 10.5), Quaternion.identity);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`9.0` is a `double`, not a `float`; try `9.0f` and `10.5f` instead; since `0` is naturally an `int`, it shouldn't *need* a suffix (since an `int` can be assigned to a `float`), but it wouldn't hurt to use `0f` if that is clearer to the reader.

Comment: Yeah. it worked. Thanks a lot. Can't believe it was this simple.